# Why is there such a difference between "" and " " in .split()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

So I have this code

```
  function upperCase (text) {

    let arr = text.split(" ");
    let arr2 = [];

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr2.push(arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+arr[i].slice(1));      
    }

    return arr2.join(" ");

}

console.log(upperCase("something something"));
```

The current output is Something Something. But if I change the values in both .join() from .join(" ") to .join(""), the output is all capitalized (SOMETHING SOMETHING). I dont understand why does this happen? How does one space between "" make all characters capitalized?

Comment: *Splitting on an empty string gives you an array with each individual character.* Then, you call `toUpperCase` on each one, then rejoin them, resulting in an all caps string.

Comment: Output `arr.length` (or the complete `arr`) in both scenarios and you will better understand what happens.

Comment: @CRice you beat me by a minute+change, but I swear I was typing my answer at the same time - want to answer youself?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Nope, there's no need when there is a perfectly good answer already, Instead I'll just upvote yours. :)

Answer (score 2):

`split(" ")` splits it into `"something","something"`

`split("")` splits it into `"s","o","m","e","t","h","i","n","g", "s","o","m","e","t","h","i","n","g"`

The uppercasing is done because you operate on lots of 1 element lists in the second case and every one gets its first character uppercased.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of `split()` states the character on witch the string is split. So if you provide a blank space `" "` your string will split on every "word". 
But if you provide no character at all with `""`, the string will get split on every position, like Patrick Artner pointed out.

You could also split on comma `","` or semicolon `";"` or anything else.